# Why is Git not found after installing OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, migration

I just upgraded to OS X Lion and now cannot initialize Git where it used to work fine:

```
$ git add .

-bash: git: command not found
```

I'm new to Git and to programming, so I'm sure it's a quick fix, any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks guys!

Comment: do you have macports installed?

Comment: i do not...do you recommend installing?

Comment: personally I would install it using homebrew instead of macports - http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: `brew > ports`, also maybe git just isn't in your `$PATH` any longer. Try `sudo find / -name git` and you might just find your binary.

Comment: hmm...not sure i fully understand.  i ran the proposed `find` command and got a lot of "Permission denied".

Comment: Why would you recommend Macports or Homebrew just for git? Just curious. I've been using http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Lion (and Snow Leopard) didn't ship with `git` - so perhaps the way you installed git didn't survive the upgrade. You'll need to find your copy of git or just get a new copy. Using spotlight to search your Time Machine backups might be fruitful to find the files and know if it's a path issue or the binaries are truly gone after Lion migrated your data.

All of your repos stored in user space are fine. Do try to get the same or newer version of git.

The command line `mdfind -name git` will list all files that spotlight has seen with git in the name. Most installations of `git` should survive an upgrade to Lion and you only have to clean up your environment or link to the binary from somewhere in your `$PATH`.

[Xcode 4](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12)(4.0-4.2) drops git into `/Developer/usr/bin` along with most of the other tools you need like make and gcc. It might be simplest to maintain git after getting the (currently) free Xcode from the App Store. Xcode 4.3 puts giy and other tools in `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`.

To avoid issues with different versions, you might want to make sure any old versions are gone from your hard drive. (and certainly from your $PATH)

Comment: AWESOME! I posted this question while downloading the new Xcode.  Just checked now and it works!  Thanks @Johan Nordberg

Comment: Where does XCode 4 for Lion put the git binary? It doesn't appear in PATH post installation.

Comment: Note XCode for Lion just *installs the installer*. You'll need to visits your apps folder and run a install app to have git.

Comment: Why would I have to install XCode to get git? Look at anler's answer for a solution that works without a 4 gb download

Comment: I have Git in `/usr/bin/git`. I installed Xcode 4 on a clean (reformat) install of Lion and I don’t remember ever running the Git installer.

Comment: I have Lion (10.7.3) and just installed XCode via the App store. It's in the Applications directory and not Developer. In fact I don't even have a /Developer directory.

Comment: Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Install Command Line Tools. See my answer below.

Answer (score 72):

If /usr/local/git already exists, you'll need to either add it to your $PATH or make a symlink placing the symlink inside a directory that is in your existing PATH.

A common practice is to make `/usr/local/bin` if it doesn't exist and add a link:

```
sudo -s
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git
exit
```

Comment: this is the proper answer

Comment: /usr/local/git exist but I get: "ln: /usr/local/bin/git: No such file or directory."

Comment: This is what we needed I guess. It does what it should do. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what fixes the problem; this should have been marked as the correct answer

Comment: Better answer than downloading 4 gigs of Xcode!

Comment: Even though the majority of people will have git installed in /usr/local/git perhaps the OP appreciated thhe general answer. Anyone who wants to re-ask this question stating the chosen answer here didn't work could then select this answer when it gets provided. No harm in two valid questions with two valid answers.

Comment: Worked great for me. FWIW, I installed Git in Snow Leopard using the Git Mac OS X installer (not XCode), before upgrading to Lion.

Comment: this worked for me, thank you very much. This is the correct answer.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked on my latest bleeding build of Yosemite. Thanks. This was what was needed. I installed the git from the github website one more time before this - if that helps anyone else.

Answer (score 21):

If you have XCode installed, the best solution is Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Install Command Line Tools.

This put git (among other things) at /usr/bin/git.

If you don't have Xcode installed, then installing it just for git would definitely be overkill.

Comment: Thanks for this - definitely the easiest way to go if you already have XCode installed.

Answer (score 15):

I think you will find that Git is still installed on your system.  It looks like the PATH is just messed up.  Check to see if /usr/local/git still exists on your system.

I just added the following to my ~/.bashrc file and everything is back to normal.

```
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

To be more specific, this site - http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html - details the difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile. If you use Mac's terminal with Git, then adding the above PATH specification to your .bash_profile will do the job. Of course, you'll have to close the Terminal window and open a new one because the .bash_profile file is loaded on a Terminal window's opening.

In summary, adding this to .bash_profile would work too.

Comment: That's exactly what I did too and git is working again.

Comment: This is the correct solution. It's only the PATH that is messed up. The other answers people have given here are workarounds, rather than the solution.

Comment: I tried doing this, but still get a command not found error when trying git add. Do I need to completely restart my computer to get the path to update?

Comment: Did you restart your terminal?  Or `source` your .bash_profile file?  Just type `source .bash_profile` in your terminal while in your home dir

Comment: yes, I restarted my terminal. I'm not sure what source means, but the answer by ing0 below (minus the reinstall of git) worked for me. Possibly my bashrc file was in the wrong place. In any case, it's working now.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Reinstall git (I just installed the Snow Leopard version from [here](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.7.6-i386-snow-leopard.dmg&can=3&q=)) if it's not in:

> /usr/local

Step 2: Open Terminal and do the following:

> cd /etc
>
> sudo nano bashrc

Then in nano at the top of the file write (as aaron suggested)

> PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH

Press Ctrl+X to quit nano and press Y to save. Then exit terminal and reopen and git should be working for you.

Comment: You shouldn't need to reinstall Git.  I believe you will find it is still installed.  Check /usr/local/git

Comment: Mine had gone completely. So I reinstalled. Like I said, if it's there then there's no need to do it!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Everything worked fine before the Lion upgrade--this was a quicker solution than downloading the 4+ GB XCode.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly, you had installed `git` through MacPorts or Fink.

I think it will take some time to have a release of either for Lion... or possibly you should try and reinstall it...

Indeed, it seems that you need to [install MacPorts from trunk](http://mac-and-i.blogspot.com/2011/05/lion-preview-installing-macports.html) to get Lion compatibility...

Fink has also got [some hints about upgrading to Lion](http://www.finkproject.org/).

Comment: I had macports installed and working before my Lion upgrade. My port command still works fine (ex: port selfupdate) but now my installed ports (ex: git) do not. I can see the packages are still in /opt/local/var. I thought it may be a $PATH issue, but ~/.profile still has my previous (before upgrade) macports configurations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Adam Tootle: See the "install MacPorts from trunk" bit in my answer...

Comment: I wasn't sure if I needed that or not since it was working ;)

If I do that I shouldn't have to reinstall all of my packages should I?

Comment: @Adam Tootle: I do think so... the point is that with Lion all system frameworks and libraries have changed (as usual with a major release)...

Comment: ahh..gotcha. well there goes any productivity for the afternoon haha

Answer (score 1):

From StackOverflow:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/
```

then run source `~/.bash_profile in Terminal`

Link to the post there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810059/git-on-mac-os-x-lion/6810082#6810082

Answer (score 1):

If you are using brew, just run this command from the terminal.

`brew install git`

Answer (score 1):

This happened because git stop being part of the $PATH (for some migration reason).

There is a very simple way of fixing this in OS X:

In OS X, you can add variables to `$PATH` by changing the file

```
/etc/paths
```

so, you can put back git doing the following:

```
sudo vim /etc/paths
```

add `/usr/local/git/bin` to the end of the file, save, and exit. Restart shell. Git should work.

Comment: /etc, are you sure? Shouldn't this rather be /usr?

Answer (score 0):

Just download the newest version from here: http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/

Install it, open up a new terminal, and it works like before :D

Comment: Link to the package list: http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3&q=&sort=-uploaded&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, downloaded and installed the snow leopard version from google code and off I went. Needed to quit and re-open terminal though...

All is well again..

Answer (score 0):

When there is git path already,

just add directory to your PATH variable.

`echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by downloading and reinstalling git from [here.](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3)

Answer (score 0):

I used the App Store to install Xcode and it just gives you an all in one app blob.  However it DOES have other apps and installers in it.  I just needed git so the path from that is 
`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`

Its a bit of a hack, but I don't use Xcode for a lot of stuff.  Add to your bash config as other posters described and your good to go

Comment: Instead of messing with $PATH it's actually easier to install the Command Line Utilities from within Xcode and use /usr/bin/git afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the path or install the Xcode command-line tools. Just use the "xcrun" utility from the Terminal:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by following advice on this site:

http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=740

It was just a pathing issue. To be honest, I expected a whole lot more issues. The upgrades are getting smoother. I remember when I upgraded from Tiger to Leopard, just about everything "open source" broke..